# Como criar Server no PostgreSQL com porta diferente de 5432?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, administração-postgresql

É possível criar um server dentro do banco Postgresql com uma porta diferente de 5432 ?

É possivel ter 
 Server1: Postgresql na porta 5432 e
 Server2: Teste na porta 5433 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere o arquivo:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3
```

A linha:

```
PGPORT=5432
```

Depois recarregue o serviço:

```
service postgresql-9.3 restart
service postgresql-9.3 reload
```

Comment: Estou suando o windows! Como ficaria ? E detalhe estou usando conta de usuário comum !

Comment: E qual o arquivo devo alterar ???

Comment: No windows eu não sei, mas se for a mesma ideia do linux você pode olhar em services.msc

Comment: Qual o arquivo devo alterar ?

Comment: Porque você não cria usuários diferentes, e concede permissões para determinado banco? É melhor que criar duas sessões com portas diferentes não?

Comment: Como faco isso ?

Comment: É muita coisa para poder explicar aqui, mas tem este link aqui: http://www.devmedia.com.br/gerenciando-usuarios-e-permissoes-no-postgresql/14301